# property then does not exist on type when call new class

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am a bit green with typescript so not sure what I am not doing right here. I have a class `retriver.ts`:

```
import * as rets from 'rets-client';

export class retsRetrv {

    results: any;

    constructor(
        private auth: any,
        private options: any
    ) {

        rets.getAutoLogoutClient(auth, (client) => {
            client.search.query(options.opt1, options.opt2, options.opt3)
                .then(data => {
                    return this.results = data.results;
                });
        });
    }

}
```

that I then need to use in my index.ts to call multiple times so that i can use some other classes within the response and so I am trying this:

```
// import rets retriver
import { retsRetrv } from './retriever/retriver';

// import auths
import { norris } from './norris/auth/norris';
import { mcars } from './mcars/auth/mcars';

// run norris
new retsRetrv(norris.login, norris.options).then(data => {
    console.log(data);
});

//run mcars
mcars.options.opt2.forEach(type => {
   // console.log(type.type);
   let options = {
       opt1: mcars.options.opt1,
       opt2: type.type,
       opt3: mcars.options.opt3,
   }
   new retsRetrv(mcars.login, options);
});
```

dealing only with the norris instance for right now to get that working, but when I try `.then()` here TS linting is telling me `property then does not exist on type retsRetrv`

am I missing something here?

Comment: What part of the error don't you understand? Why do you expect it to exist?

Comment: You are treating a class like a promise.

Comment: i guess I need to understand then how to handle the return then once I have it. Sorry for my ignorance, I am trying to learn!

Comment: dealing with classes and promises are still kinda new to me!

Comment: I personally would take that piece of code in your constructor, place it in its own function, and call that after you create your object.

Comment: I would start from scratch. You are treating your class like a promise and are creating a world of hurt for your future self.

Comment: @chrisz so you mean my constructor would hold the arguments only then create a method after. so i would call with something like `new retsRetrv.newMethod(arg1, arg2, arg3).then(data => { //do something })` ?